# Pandas: Remove rows with zero value in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

(picture is a snapshot of my df)

I want to remove the rows that have a zero value. I don't want to modify the DataFrame, but create an assignment which reflects the DataFrame with no zero values in the 'amount spent' column.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Example: `df[df['amount_spent'] != 0]`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax can be used to view (index) a DataFrame based on a given condition:

```
# View whole DataFrame where `amount_spent` is not zero.
df[df['amount_spent'] != 0]
```

[Here is the official pandas documentation on indexing.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

What's happening?
The `df['amount_spent'] != 0` statement returns a 'mask' as a boolean array (`Series`), which is then passed into the 'rows parameter index' (if you will) of the overall DataFrame as: `df[<masked_array>]`.

This will create a 'view' of the DataFrame and not alter it in any way.